# Python retrieve QComboBox from QTablewidget

Tags: python, qwidget, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I am now a month into Python and half a month into QDesigner/Qt.
Within QDesigner, I have a QTableWidget, which I promote to my own InputTable(QTableWidget) class.

```
class InputTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super(QTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
...
```

I inserted some QComboboxes, which allow the user to select the units of the values in the table. This is at the initialization within the InputTable class.

```
pressureunits = [ "barg","bara", "psig", "psia"]
        pressurecombobox = QComboBox()
        for i in range(len(pressureunits)):
            pressurecombobox.addItem(pressureunits[i])
            self.setCellWidget(2, 0, pressurecombobox)
```

So far, so good.

Now I want to convert all the inputdata to a parallel table (master table) with values in SI units for further analysis.

```
units = self.tableInputs.cellWidget(2,0)
if units.currentIndex()==0:   # this means the combobox is at the first entry
    mastertable[0,2] = float(self.tableInputs.item(2,1).text())
```

This fails, because units is of type QWidget, which has no attribute currentIndex. On some forums I read that the QComboBox is a child of the QWidget and I have played with the children() functions, but helas no solution here. Some people recommend switching to QTableView structure. I spend my day searching how to do this, nothing found yet. Any smart ideas?

Update: After reducing all complexity from my question, I was able to find the solution below.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

Mytable = QTableWidget(3,3)
Mytable.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("1"))
print("Now retrieve the data :", Mytable.item(0, 0).text())

pressureunits = [ "barg","bara", "psig", "psia"]
pressurecombobox = QComboBox()
for i in range(len(pressureunits)):
    pressurecombobox.addItem(pressureunits[i])
    Mytable.setCellWidget(2, 0, pressurecombobox)
print("Now retrieve the active (first) entry :", Mytable.cellWidget(2,0).currentText())
```

Comment: 1. It looks like your code formatting got mangled in the question.

Comment: 2. if units.currentIndex()==0:

Comment: I updated according to comment no. 2. I am not sure how I can unmangle no.1. Thanks JRE by the way for looking into this. I am getting nuts here.